# How to only utilise certain class of the element based on its parent class without using JavaSctript?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do the following: when div container has the class `show`, the span will only use class `pseudo2` otherwise will use class `pseudo1`. There is a predefined css file that I don't want to modify, and I have pasted my custom css file, however it doesn't seem to work. Anyone know better solution?

**html**

```
   <div class="container">
       <h2>
         <span aria-hidden="true" class="pseudo1 pseudo2"></span>
       </h2>
   </div>
```

**predefined css**

```
.pseudo1:before{
   content:"/012";
}
.pseudo2:before{
   content:"/013";
}
```

**my custom css**

```
.show .pseudo1:before{
   content:none;
}    
.show .pseudo2:before{
   content:"/013";
}    
.pseudo2:before{
       content:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS cascading order is very important:

```
.show .pseudo2:before{
   content:"/013";
}    
.show .pseudo1:before{
   content:none;
}
```

Now, `.show .pseudo1:before` is more relevant. Also you can use the `!important`.

See how works: http://jsfiddle.net/btj62bfv/1/.

Read about [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order) in the [W3 webpage](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order).

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need the `content:none;` to get this done, see the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lado0kmp/)**:

**Your predefined css file that you don't want to modify**

```
.pseudo1:before{
   content:"/012";
}
.pseudo2:before{
   content:"/013";
}
```

**Your custom css**

```
.pseudo1:before{
   content:"/012";
}

.show .pseudo2:before{
   content:"/013";
}
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do ?

Comment: it worked, but I wonder why after repeatedly define the same style in custom css it works...

Comment: @FabianMebus You just edited your code, you forgot to put .show on last part, that's why I asked.

Comment: But well, you got the point : content:none; was making some trouble on his code.

Comment: @Blake If you assign exactly the same CSS property (e.g. `content:"/012";`) to the same element twice somewhere in your CSS, always the last one will *win*.

Comment: @FabianMebus yes.. I understand, but here in the predefined css, the content is already `content:"/012"` and why define it a second time in custom css?

Comment: @Blake In the predefined CSS you set the `content` property of the pseudo element `:before` of the `span` element at first (`.pseudo1`) to **/012** and afterwards to **/013** (`.pseudo2`). So the value of the `content` property is **/013**. 
To set the *default* value (without `.show`) in your custom CSS to **/012**, you first need `.pseudo1:before { content:"/012"; }`. 
It would be much easier without the predefined CSS, that is for sure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! What I meant is that in the predefined css file, it sets `.pseudo1:before{
   content:"/012";
}` and in the custom css file, again we set `.pseudo1:before{
   content:"/012";
}` , since the content is the same, what does this snippet in custom css suppose to override?

Answer (score 0):

**I think using the classes .pseudo1 and .pseudo2 is a bit confusing**, so I did something *simplier* :

```
/* predefined css */

.pseudo1:before{
   content:"/012";

}
.pseudo2:before{
   content:"/013";
}


/* my custom css */

.container span:before{
   content:"/012";
}    
.container.show span:before{
   content:"/013";
}
```

It's basically **overriding the predefined rules**, but IMHO it's easier to read.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lado0kmp/1/